# Access denied CloudFormation cross account s3 copy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I've looked through hours of documentation and don't feel like I'm missing anything, but I obviously am. I have S3 objects in source account I want to copy to an S3 bucket in dest account. Here's my setup (note I deliberately made permissions pretty loose initially just to get this to work. Planning on scoping this down later):

Role created by Cloudformation that the lambda assumes in `source_account`:

```
CopyRole:
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'CopyRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: [ 'sts:AssumeRole' ]
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: [ lambda.amazonaws.com ]
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Action: [ 'logs:CreateLogStream', 'logs:PutLogEvents', 'logs:CreateLogGroup' ]
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
              - Action: [ 's3:*', 'kms:*' ]
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
              - Action: [ 'sts:AssumeRole' ]
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: '*'
          PolicyName: CopyPolicy
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
```

Note that the above is given the ability to assume any other role.

IAM role in dest_account `DestAccountCopyRole` which should give read permissions from source bucket (other account) and write permissions to destination bucket (in same account)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLogging",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetBucketNotification",
                "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetBucketCORS",
                "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dest_account_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
... trust policy which allows the lambda role to assume this role
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::source_account:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

`source_account` bucket policy which allows the IAM role in destination account to read from the source bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::dest_account:role/DestAccountCopyRole"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_account_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source_account_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`dest_account` bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::dest_account:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dest_account_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dest_account_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My lambda run on javascript is able to get past the part of assuming the cross account role, but fails with `Access Denied` when attempting to copy the data over

```
const creds = await getCredentials(destination_bucket)
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                });
s3Dest = new aws.S3(creds);

return s3.listObjects(sourcePath).promise()
  .then(async (data) => {
     return Promise.all(data.Contents.map((item) => {
       console.log(`Copying data over`);
       s3Dest.copyObject({
         Bucket: destination_bucket,
         CopySource: copy_source,
         Key: key
       }).promise();
     }));
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    throw err;
  });

const getCredentials = async (bucket) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::dest_account:role/DestAccountCopyRole",
            RoleSessionName: 'copy-test'
        };
        sts.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                console.log(data);
                resolve({
                    accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                    secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                    sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I don't think I know enough about Javascript either because the cloudwatch logs are printing both `Copying data over` and `Error: Access Denied` then failing (I figured the `Error: Access Denied` would only show up if the `listObjects` call failed, but it looks like it's able the items and just fail at the copying portion)

Comment: " part of assuming the cross account role" - where is it? You JS code does not show any assumeRole operation.

Comment: @Marcin added an edit

Comment: Worst case, if you wish, is to use the IAM Role assigned to the Lambda function instead of assuming an IAM Role from a different account. It would need: (1) IAM Role on Lambda function has permission to read from source bucket and write to destination bucket, and (2) Destination bucket needs a Bucket Policy that permits access to the IAM Role used by the Lambda function.

Comment: Both the source and destination bucket are server side encrypted with SSE-S3 (not KMS) so this wouldn't be an issue with a missing KMS permission right?

Answer (score 1):

When copying objects between buckets that belong to different AWS Accounts ('cross-account copy'), the one set of credentials requires permission to both **read** from the source location and **write** to the destination location.

Since your code is assuming an IAM Role from the destination account, you will also need to **create a Bucket Policy on the source bucket** that grants permission for that IAM Role to read from the source bucket.

It does not matter than the IAM Role used by the Lambda function has permission to access the source bucket because **the `copy()` operation will be performed by the IAM Role assumed from the destination account**, so it will not use any permissions from the IAM Role assigned to the Lambda function.

Also, when granting permission for the IAM Role to write to the destination bucket, it would actually be better-practice to **grant this permission via a policy on the IAM Role itself**, rather than as a Bucket Policy. In general, a Bucket Policy should only be used when granting public access or cross-account access, rather than granting permission to simply one user.

Comment: I updated the source bucket's policy to allow the destination AWS account to read from that bucket. Re-running my code seems to work for `s3.putObject` calls, but `s3.copyObject` is still access denied. The IAM role in the destination account has a policy that allows full permissive s3 operations on any resource, so why would this be the case?

Comment: When doing cross-account copies using credentials from the destination account, three things are required: (1) The IAM Role in the destination account needs permissions to write to the destination bucket in the _same account_ -- this can be done via an IAM Policy (preferred) or a Bucket Policy; (2) The IAM Role in the destination account needs permission to read from the source bucket in the _other account_ (via an IAM Policy); (3) The Bucket policy on the source bucket needs to grant permission for the IAM Role in the other account to Read from the source bucket.

Comment: Just because an IAM Role in the destination account has been given "a policy that allows full permissive s3 operations on any resource" does _not_ mean that it can access resources in a _different_ account. Otherwise, Admin users in _my_ AWS Account could read all buckets in _your_ AWS Account.

Comment: If it is still not working, I would suggest focussing on "the source bucket's policy to allow the destination AWS account to read from that bucket". Instead of giving it to the "account", given it to the _specific_ ARN of the IAM Role from the other account and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I've carefully read over your suggestions, made the necessary changes to ensure I have all three things you're speaking of, and still getting Access Denied. I've updated my post with the permissions I'm using now